# PySide2 How to make a transparent widget background

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pyside2, xorg

I'm writing a widget that should have a transparent background.
Unfortunately, I get a black background instead of transparent.

I've used attributes like:

- `WA_TranslucentBackground`
- `WA_NoSystemBackground`

and also flags:

- Qt.FramelessWindowHint
- Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint

my system using **KWin** windows manager which is based on **x.org**

Here's a quick example of my widget:

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
import sys
from psutil import cpu_percent


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(600, 600)
        self.dark = "#3B3A44"
        self.light = "#4a4953"
        self.color = "#75ECB5"

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)

        self.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")
        # self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_PaintOnScreen)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint |
                            Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint |
                            Qt.Tool)

    def paintEvent(self, event: QPaintEvent):
        """ Dessine l'horloge """

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        base_rect = self.rect().adjusted(20, 20, -20, -20)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(self.dark)))
        painter.drawEllipse(base_rect)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.move(800, 300)
    w.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if *translucency* is enable on your KDE systemsettings.
Also you can install other tools like `xcompmgr` and execute it before starting your app.